# Android: App installation fails

Tags: android, failed-installation

When I try to run my app from eclipse on the nexus s hardware, I get a `Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY` with the advice to see Logcat. There, it says

```
W/ActivityManager(130): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/myapp.apk
I/AndroidRuntime(1725): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
```

The first message appears twice.

The Nexus S runs Android 4.0.4 while my eclipse builds the app for Android 2.3.3. When I change the target to Android 4.0.3 I still get the same error.

I also tried to copy the APK to the SD-card and installed it manually, but this also failed (silently).

The device has not been rooted by me. If I enter `whoami` to adb shell it cannot find the command. I read about missing permissions to /data/local/tmp but I could not change that (because of missing permissions).

When I try to run the emulator, I get a blank black screen but that's another issue... 
Since the app will use NFC, I can only test it on real hardware or on a emulator with a open-nfc plugin installed. I'd like the app to have minimum requirements, so I develop it for SDK Version 10 (9 was the first with NFC).

If you have to take a look at the manifest you can find it [here](http://nopaste.me/paste/15207152404f96db01e929c)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass -t switch to the package manager during installation:
`pm install -t ...`

Alternatively, you can remove the [android:testOnly](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestApplication_testOnly) property from your manifest.

Comment: i dont understand why but i could bypass the problem by copying the sourcecode to another project where (in the essential points) same code worked just fine. nevertheless thanks for your answer, i backupped the corrupt project and will try it eventually.